# Document set Unable to upload multiple documents in one time on Office 365

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-set, office-365-develop-tool

In Document Library I'm able to select multiple documents and upload in one time in document library. But when I'm creating Document Set to upload multiple documents then I'm not able to select Multiple documents in one time. Please advice.

We can use below two option upload multiple documents in Document Library and Document Set.

Open with Explorer (from SharePoint Ribbon)

Upload files using Windows Explorer (to click on Upload option)

Comment: Works fine for us. Could you specify the feedback you get? Have you tested it in regular folder, and have you tested it with an account with Site Collection Admin permissions? Web browser version you are using?

Comment: Thanks Gil for your comment. I used below two option and its working fine.:)

Comment: Gil - Here I've one issue If I'm login with Contribute or Design permission these both option is showing invisible for me. Can you please advice what permission is required to access 1) Open with Explorer - From SharePoint ribbon & 2) Upload files using Windows Explorer to upload multiple files in bulk.

Comment: Comming in late here, hope you see this. Adding the Office 365 site to Trusted Sites in Internet options may help with "Open with Explorer" functionality.